# Flutter Dio receiving gibberish

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am pulling data from eurostat but dio is receiving gibberish data even though the status code is successful, shown in this

[image: debug output]

Here is my code

```dart
class DatabaseHelperEurope extends DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelperEurope(this.code);

  //initializes the database
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    return _database ??= await _initDatabase();
  }

  String code;
  String error = "";
  final String baseUrl = "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination";
  final dio = Dio();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    var databasesPath = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var path = join(databasesPath!.path, "$code.csv");
    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
      String url =
          "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/PRC_HICP_MIDX/.I15..$code?format=SDMX-CSV";
      try {
        downloadFile(url, databasesPath!.path);
      } catch (e) {
        error = e.toString();
      }
    }

    return await openDatabase(path);
  }

  @override
  Future<IO.File?> downloadFile(String url, String path) async {
    final file = IO.File(join(path, "$code.csv"));

    final response = await dio.fetch(RequestOptions(
      baseUrl: url
    ));
    final raf = file.openSync(mode: IO.FileMode.write);
    raf.writeByte(response.data);
    debugPrint("data written");
    await raf.close();

    return file;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<DatabaseContent>> getDatabaseContent() async{
    Database db = await database;
    var databaseContents = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM europe_price_index_all WHERE geo like 'DE' and coicop like 'CP00' and unit like 'I15';");
    List<DatabaseContent> databaseContentList = databaseContents.isNotEmpty
        ? databaseContents.map((e) => DatabaseContent.fromMap(e)).toList()
        : [];
    return databaseContentList;
  }
```

I tried using fetch and get but I get the same result, I tried fetching the data from Python using requests and its output should be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDMX-CSV` != `CSV`

You are requesting a `SDMX-CSV` but trying to treat it as a normal `CSV` document. Looking at the `SDMX` homepage, it becomes clear that this data format is optimized for the exchange of data.

**In general:**
If I see this type of symbols I would always check:

1. Is the encoding right? (Setting, `UTF-8` should solve most of these issues)
2. Is there some sort of compression going on? (See documentation which compression is used) However, this was *unlikely*.
3. Is the response in the form of arbitrary binary data? (See documentation of service on how to decode it properly)

**For SDMX:**
It looks like much of the Standard is still not finished, so documentation is sparse. However I could find [this document](https://github.com/sdmx-twg/sdmx-csv/blob/master/metadata-message/docs/sdmx-csv-field-guide.md) and [this cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdmx-twg/sdmx-rest/master/doc/rest_cheat_sheet.pdf). In any case you are going to have to read a lot through the documentation in order to find out what's wrong.

I also noticed that you didn't define any headers, so I would suggest adding the following (it's also noted in the documentation):

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.sdmx.data+csv; version=1.0.0
```